# something is capable of to be p.p. or being p.p.?

Tags: differences, infinitives, gerunds, gerund-vs-infinitive

> Manual: *small, helpful book capable of being carried in the hand.*

What is the difference between *to be carried* and *being carried* in this sentence?

Comment: An infinitive (_to do_) cannot be the object of a preposition. You use the gerund (_doing_) instead—that’s one of its basic uses: to function as an infinitive in contexts where an infinitive cannot grammatically occur.

Comment: @Janus: I feel able to disagree with that formulation.

Comment: @TimLymington, that’s not an infinitive (including ‘to’) being the object of a preposition. That would have been ‘able to to disagree’. As Colin says, that’s simply ‘able’ + infinitive.

Answer (score 2):

Many words (particularly verbs, but also adjectives) limit the kind of construction they can take as their object.

*Able* and *capable* can have similar meanings, but take a different kind of complement:

*Able* requires an infinitive phrase: *able to be carried*

*Capable* requires *of*, and therefore a gerund phrase *capable of being carried*.

There's no reason for this: it just happens to be how these words work in English.

Comment: The book able to be carried or The book capable of being carried? which one do you use?

Comment: Random House Kernerman Webster's College Dictionary actually defines the adjective + preposition construction: . . . 2. **capable of**
a. having the ability for: capable of writing music. //
b. susceptible of: a situation capable of improvement. //
c. predisposed to: capable of murder.

Comment: @nima_persian: both are good. _Capable_ perhaps has the connotation of having a specific ability, so is less likely in the passive (_capable of being X_) but this construction does occur. _Able to be carried_ is probably more lakely in everyday language.

Comment: WHICH ONE DO YOU USE?